# What if LICQ does not hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose given a nonlinear optimization programming:

$min_{x,y} f(x,y)$ st

$g_1(x,y)\ge 0$ , $g_2(x,y)\ge 0$ , $g_3(x,y)\ge 0$

and suppose that at the solution $(x*, y*)$ the three constraints are active. This means that the constraints gradients will not be linearly dependent and the LICQ fails to hold. How could we handle this case since the LICQ is a necessary condition for optimality.

Comment: There are also other regularity conditions that can be used (where the KKT conditions are the same), LICQ is just among the most common. It simplifies things a great deal. See the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Regularity_conditions_(or_constraint_qualifications)).

Answer (score 1):

LICQ is not a necessary condition for optimality. It is a prerequisite that the KKT conditions are necessary for optimality.

You might check other constraint qualifications (MFCQ, linearity, convexity + Slater point, etc).

LICQ fails trivially if $g_1=g_2=g_3$. Nevertheless, Lagrange multipliers might exist as other constraint qualifications might hold.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I am referring to the book: "Numerical optimization, Nocedal" where the necessary conditions for optimality are stated. The theorem supposes that LICQ holds. Now what are the necessary conditions if the LICQ does not hold?